# Is there any particular downside to adding MAX() to all fields to weed out duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am using SQL Server 2016. I have a large table with 30+ columns. When I pull the data I need from it there are occasionally duplicated rows. I imagine this is because there is some difference in one of the columns that I'm not using, but for my purposes the data is always the same. What I have done is change

```
SELECT
    [reference], [name], [postcode], [type], [amount]
FROM
    [my table]
```

To

```
SELECT
    [reference], MAX([name]), MAX([postcode]), MAX([type]), MAX([amount])
FROM
    [my table]
GROUP BY 
    [reference]
```

Is this likely to cause any problems? Either in hugely increased processing time or potential errors?

Comment: It really depends on your data.  It will certainly add some overhead, but how much really depends on what your data looks like and how it's indexed.  Try running the query yourself and see the difference.

Comment: Why not use distinct?

Comment: Since you state that all values are the same you could just group by all the columns. Or even simpler add distinct to your query.

Comment: Why not put a bit of effort into figuring out what WHERE clause to use to weed up these rows in the first place, rather than hiding them later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine.  A more typical approach is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [reference], [name], [postcode], [type], [amount]
FROM [my table] t;
```

I would expect this to have the same performance as the `GROUP BY`, but you can check.  Sometimes, this may optimize differently.

An alternative method is:

```
SELECT [reference], [name], [postcode], [type], [amount]
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [reference], [name], [postcode], [type], [amount]
                                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM [my table] t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You might want to test and see which performs better.

Comment: I've always felt that using DISTINCT/GROUP BY to squish unexpected duplicates is like bringing a mop and bucket to a riot, instead of a bulletproof vest :)

Comment: I like partition by, but for large tables with varchar columns this can spill a lot into the temporary db. You could also group by the necessary fields and select the max/min primary key and join that on the same table. But I don't know if that might be faster. As you say, it should be tested.